# Baffling "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function"

Tags: t-sql, exception, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a very simple query, as such:

`SELECT * FROM production.LINE_JOB_QUEUE WHERE L_ROWID = 33 ORDER BY SEQNO`

When I try to run it using ADO.NET, I get the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   at System.Data.Common.LoadAdapter.FillFromReader(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   at System.Data.DataTable.Load(IDataReader reader, LoadOption loadOption, FillErrorEventHandler errorHandler)
   at System.Data.DataTable.Load(IDataReader reader, LoadOption loadOption)
   at Temporal.DBO.Definitions.DBBroker`3.ExecuteDT(String SQL, Int32 TimeoutSeconds) in C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\Development\Framework v.4\Temporal Libraries\Temporal.DBO\Definitions\DbBroker.vb:line 81
```

Thing is, as you can see above, my query contains neither `LEFT` nor `SUBSTRING`. The view which is being queried (`production.LINE_JOB_QUEUE`) is does not contain them either, and is comprised only of tables (no other views) and none of these tables have calculated columns using either of those function either.

The view's code is such:

```
ALTER VIEW [production].[LINE_JOB_QUEUE] AS 
SELECT
   l.ROWID as L_ROWID, l.code, q.rowid Q_ROWID, r.rowid as R_ROWID,
   L.NAME AS QUEUENAME, P.SKU AS ITEMNO, P.NAME AS DESCR,
   Q.lotno, q.orderqty, q.SEQNO,q.ONEOFF,l.IsUp, l.IsLocked,l.IsPortOpen,r.IsHeld,
   case 
     when isnull(q.ACTIVE,0) = 1 then 'ACTIVE'   -- active: 0=inactive; 1=active
     when r.canceldate IS not null then 'CANCELLED'
     when r.enddate IS not null then 'COMPLETED'
     else 'PENDING'
   end as STATUS, q.proddate, qa.itemno as cur_itemno,qa.name as cur_descr,
   isnull(ra.lineisactive,0)lineisactive, isnull(q.ACTIVE,0) q_active,
   r.startdate, r.enddate,
   case  
     when r.startdate is null then null
     else system.udfTimeSpanFromSeconds(DATEDIFF(SECOND, R.STARTDATE, ISNULL(R.ENDDATE, GETDATE()))) 
   end AS ELAPSED   
FROM catalog.PRODUCTS P, production.Queue Q
        left join production.RUN r on q.rowid = r.rowid,   
     production.LINES L  
        left join
          (select q.lineid, q.itemno, p.name 
            from production.queue q, catalog.products p
            where p.sku = q.itemno and q.active = 1 ) QA on qa.lineid = L.rowid   
        left join (select lineid,max( cast(active as integer) ) as lineisactive 
                      from production.RUN group by lineid ) RA on ra.lineid = l.rowid    
where l.rowid = q.lineid and 
      P.SKU = q.ITEMNO
```

While I get the above error when running the query in ADO.NET, I can run the same query in SSMS, and it runs perfectly fine, with no exceptions, every single time.

I saw one posting online, where someone had the same problem because the log file location had run out of space, and freeing up space solved the problem for them. However in our case, the log file location has 133 GB free space, so that is not the issue. But just to be thorough, I shrunk the database and logs. No help. I have tried restarting the Sql Server instance, no luck. I have also tried rebooting the server, all with no luck.

The database server is Sql Server 2008 R2, running on a Windows Server 2008 SP2 machine.
The app is a .NET 4 website running in IIS6 on a Windows Server 2003 R2 machine.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: is `udfTimeSpanFromSeconds` a function you have defined? I suspect you have SUBSTRING or LEFT in that, and that the reason it doesn't fail in SSMS but via your code is due to the differences in date/time format sent to the query.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen is right. issue might be custom function udfTimeSpanFromSeconds. Can you please post the code of this function to help you better!!

Comment: Allan, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Yes, Allan, please post that as an answer, and I will accept it. That's what it was. That function is one of the few pieces of the system which I did not write, and so my eyes just glossed right past it. It was trying to do SUBSTRINGs to remove leading/trailing characters, which were not there. Fixed those, and it's now all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposted comment as answer:

is udfTimeSpanFromSeconds a function you have defined? I suspect you have SUBSTRING or LEFT in that, and that the reason it doesn't fail in SSMS but via your code is due to the differences in date/time format sent to the query.